# MS Access: Compound greater than less than comparisons

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

The question is simple: Why does this give the wrong answer (0)

```
IIf(Date()>=#3/16/2018#>=Date()-30,1,0)
```

While this gives the correct answer (1)

```
IIf(Date()>=#3/16/2018# AND #3/16/2018#>=Date()-30,1,0)
```

More specifically, what is Access doing in the first case?

This situation is made even more curious because, when I execute this code, I get an unexpected answer (1)

```
IIf(Date()<=#3/16/2018#<=Date()-30,1,0)
```

Comment: in vba `Date()>=#3/16/2018#>=Date()-30` is asking if `Date()>=` a boolean that is created by `#3/16/2018#>=Date()-30` this will return TRUE or FALSE to the first part and if True it will ask if `Date()>=1` and if FALSE: `Date()>=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compound comparisons in Access!

Using your last example, Access first executes the first comparison:

```
Date()<=#3/16/2018#
```

That might result in `True` or `False`. Let's say it's `True`

Then, Access evaluates the second comparison:

```
True <= Date() - 30
```

(This is since they're processed from left to right, and the first one is true).

This doesn't make much sense, but Access can cast a boolean to a number (-1 = True, 0 = False), and a date too (for example, today = 43186, since dates are defined as the number of days elapsed since 1899-12-30).

That means the second comparison results in:

```
-1 <= 43186 - 30
```

And that's certainly true. You also see that if the first comparison is false, the second one will be true nonetheless. Your comparison will pretty much always return true.

Comment: I had figured that I couldn't compound from its behavior, but I became curious why it was giving me wildly erroneous answers instead of crashing. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, any non-zero numeric value cast to a Boolean will be `True`. `-1` just happens to be the hard-wired value for the numeric representation of `True`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon As far as I know, comparing a boolean to a date leads to implicit casting of both to numerical values (doubles). I couldn't find good documentation on it, but `Debug.Print True <= #1-1-1800#` prints `False` because the internally used double is less than -1

Comment: Yeah. `Year(CDate(0))` is 1899 =)